# How to find mean vector and covariance from a matrix

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose $U$ is normal with mean $-1$ and variance $1$, $V$ is normal with mean $1$ and variance $1$, and $Z$ is defined as $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}U \\ V \end{bmatrix}$. I want to find the mean vector and covariance matrix.

Now first thing I did was multiply out the matrix so we know $Z = \begin{bmatrix}U + V \\ U - 2V \end{bmatrix}$.

However I am not sure how I can find the mean or covariance from this. Should I be finding them row by row? i.e. the mean vector would have the top row be the mean of $U + V$ and the bottom row be the mean of $U - 2V$? I'm having trouble finding reference material on this matter.

Comment: The answers to your questions are based on the concept of _linearity of expectation_ which means that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then $$E[aX+bY] = aE[X]+bE[Y].\tag{1}$$ There are _no_ restrictions on the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ for this to hold: $X$ and $Y$ could be independent or dependent, uncorrelated or correlated, normal or nonnormal, continuous or discrete, related in any fashion (e.g. $Y=g(X)$) or whatever, $(1)$ still  applies.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Presumably $U$ and $V$ are supposed to be independent.  If you do not know this, then you can still find the expectation of $Z$ but not the variance-covariance matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for random vector $X$ and constant matrices $A,b$, the mean and covariance matrix of $AX+b$ are given by

$$E[AX+b]=AE[X]+b\\
\text{Var}(AX+b)=A\text{Var}(X)A'.$$

In your setup, you can compute these if you also know the covariance between $U$ and $V$, which will be the off-diagonal entries of the covariance matrix for $(U,V)'.$